# Understand an awk command that converts column values to rows

Tags: awk

This command converts the column values to rows. 
Command:

```
awk -s1=" " '{S=S?S OFS s1 $0 s1:s1 $0 s1} END{print S}' OFS=,  Input_file
```

example:

```
1
2
3
```

is converted to:

```
1, 2, 3
```

Can anyone please help me understand this command?

Comment: please fix your awk call. You probably mean `-v s1=" "`. And even then, your output will be " 1 , 2 , 3 " (with some extra spaces).

Comment: FYI that awk command has several issues. Assuming you don't mind a blank line output if the input file is empty `awk -v OFS=', ' '{S=(NR>1 ? S OFS : "") $0} END{print S}' file` or using less memory `awk '{printf "%s%s", s, $0; s=", "} END{print ""}' file` are the ways to do what that command is trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to know that syntax:

```
var = bool ? true_action : false_action
```

This is called [Conditional Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Conditional-Exp.html#Conditional-Exp)

It is the same as

```
if (bool) { var = true_action } else { var = false_action }
```

So, this:

```
 S=S?S OFS s1 $0 s1:s1 $0 s1
```

Is the same as this:

```
if (S) { S=S OFS s1 $0 s1 } else { S = s1 $0 s1 }
```

- `if (S)` will be true if `S` has been assigned, so it is only false for the first time your command is called.
- `var1 var2 var3` is just concatenating strings, with `s1` being a space, `OFS` being `,` and `S` whatever has been assigned before.
- `END{print S}` will print `S` after the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with Below sed  and perl command

```
perl -pne "s/\n/,/g" filename| sed "s/,$//g"
```

output

```
1,2,3
```

Comment: You could do that sed command inside Perl...

Comment: Do you think this answer is related to the question asked?